# Do I need a visa to transit Canada?

Tags: canada, transit-visas, pakistani-citizens, trinidad-and-tobago

I am Pakistani and I have a flight from Cyprus, via Toronto, to Trinidad. Do I need a visa for connecting my flight from Toronto?

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: I am Pakistani national